# JavaFX Button minWidth ignored

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, when a component's `minWidth` is set to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, the component's minimum width is calculated based on its content.

While I've successfully used this for many components, it doesn't seem to work as expected for `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>


<Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="This should always be visible" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

[image]
[image]

So I tested what happens when setting `minWidth` to 300:

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

In order to test if the stage ignores the button's `minWidth`, I wrapped the button into an HBox and added a margin around the button.
With the `minWidth` set to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, this is the result:

[image]
[image]

When I set `minWidth` to 200, I get:

[image]

Which is good - except that I need the size to be computed.

Comment: You should use `USE_PREF_SIZE`. `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` is the size that the control thinks that it can render itself - for a `Button` is is very small because it can put `ellipsis` for the text.

Comment: Using `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` does ***not*** prevent the ellipsis. (Just print the result of `button.minWidth(-1)` after the first layout pass.) Using `USE_PREF_SIZE` for the `minWidth` and `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` for `prefWidth` would set the constraints correctly, but resizing the stage (and scene) can force a node to violate it's size constraints. You need to set the `minWidth` of the stage you use to display the scene.

Comment: @fabian That works! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX API documentation says:

> Defaults to the `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` flag, which means that
>   `minWidth(forHeight)` will return the region's internally computed
>   minimum width.
>
> Setting this value to the `USE_PREF_SIZE` flag will cause
>   `minWidth(forHeight)` to return the region's preferred width, enabling
>   applications to easily restrict the resizability of the region.